# Директива pragma once

Tags: c++

Директива `#pragma once` распространяется на один подключаемый файл или на все?

**UPDATE**:
Понял, она распростаняется на сам файл. Тогда почему, когда я в файле указал #pragma once и пытаюсь его подключить к другим файлам(нескольким) выдаются ошибки линковки:

```
1>error LNK2005: "void __cdecl logit(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,int,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?logit@@YAXV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@H0@Z) already defined in file2.obj
1>error LNK2005: "class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl GetTime(void)" (?GetTime@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ) already defined in file2.obj
1>error LNK2005: "void __cdecl GetDate(void)" (?GetDate@@YAXXZ) already defined in file2.obj
1>fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вы неверно понимаете эту директиву. Она распространяется на файл, в котором она определена.

То есть, ее нужно добавлять в .h файлы (те, которые подключаются с помощью `#include`) в самый верх. Она "эквивалентна" следующей, довольно популярной конструкции

```
#ifndef _GUARD_H_
#define  _GUARD_H_
//код
#endif
```

А вот проблема наблюдается потому, что Ваш h файл попадает в много разных cpp файлов. И естественно, линковщик обнаруживает много одинаковых функций и ругается. Лечиться это так. Либо просто добавьте inline  к определению функции в самое начало (но это некрасиво, особенно, если функции не маленькие), либо создайте отдельный cpp файл, вынесите туда тело каждой функции, а в h файле оставьте только прототипы. Это правильный, хороший способ. Но если Ваши функции в h файле занимают по одной-две строки, то можно и через inline.

Comment: Ну строк по 20, но их много... Сейчас попробую, спасибо

Answer (score 3):

Насколько я помню, она распространяется на текущий файл, т.е. должна находиться в заголовочном файле, а не вне его. Так что размещайте ее во всех своих подключаемых файлах...

К **Update**

Ваша проблема связана с тем, что **объявлений** допускается много, а вот **определение** - только одно. Видимо, вы размещаете в заголовочном файле определение функции, и в результате в каждом объектном файле имеется соответствующий код. И компоновщик не в состоянии понять, что же ему выбрать.

Размещайте в заголовочных файлах только объявления. Функцию - без тела, с телом - только шаблонные и `inline` (можно еще `static` или в анонимном пространстве имен, но это даст не то, что вы на самом деле хотите - функции просто будут дублированы), переменные - только `extern`.